# MassTransit not creating _error queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have two Consumers:

```
public class SendEmailConsumer : ConsumerBase, IConsumer<ISendEmail>
    {    
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISendEmail> context)
        {
            throw new Exception("aaa");
        }
    }




public class IntegrateNewCostCenterConsumer: ConsumerBase, IConsumer<IIntegrateCostCenter>
        {    
            public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISendEmail> context)
            {
                throw new Exception("aaa");
            }
        }
```

both with the same configuration:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, MessageHandlerConstants.IntegrateCostCenter, e =>
            {
                // doc http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/circuit-breaker.html
                e.UseCircuitBreaker(cb =>
                {
                    cb.TripThreshold = 15;
                    cb.ResetInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                    cb.TrackingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    cb.ActiveThreshold = 10;
                });

                e.UseRetry(r => r.Interval(5, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)));
                e.Consumer<IntegrateNewCostCenterConsumer>();
            });


cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, MessageHandlerConstants.SendEmail, e =>
            {
                // doc http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/circuit-breaker.html
                e.UseCircuitBreaker(cb =>
                {
                    cb.TripThreshold = 15;
                    cb.ResetInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                    cb.TrackingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    cb.ActiveThreshold = 10;
                });

                e.UseRetry(r => r.Interval(10, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60)));
                e.Consumer<SendEmailConsumer>();
            });
```

The problem is only IntegrateCostCenter has _error queue created sucessfuly for the exception. Both are handled normally. What i'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error queue is created only when all attempts is fails.